# .Net Apache Ignite Memory cgroup out of memory

Tags: .net, docker, ignite, cgroups

Apache Ignite Memory cgroup out of memory

I have a separate cache server program,I did a test using the latest version of Apache ignite 2.10. My console program code is as follows:

````
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Binary;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Configuration;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Common;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Discovery.Tcp;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Discovery.Tcp.Static;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Failure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace IgniteConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {

        protected Program()
        {

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            var ignite = StartIgnite();
            Console.WriteLine("StartIgnite Sucess!");
            CacheConfiguration config = new CacheConfiguration($"Test{typeof(VehicleModel).FullName}");
            var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<string, VehicleModel>(config);
            var list = GetVehicleModels().ToDictionary(x => x.Id.ToString(), x => x);

            cache.PutAll(list);

            Console.WriteLine("loop start");
            for (int j = 0; j < int.MaxValue; j++)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i <= 2500; i++)
                {
                    var data = cache.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.DumFleetNum == i.ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static List<VehicleModel> GetVehicleModels()
        {
            var list = new List<VehicleModel>();
            for (var i = 1; i <= 2500; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new VehicleModel
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Version = 0,
                    CacheUpdateDT = DateTime.UtcNow,
                    DumFleetNum = i.ToString(),
                    VehicleID = i.ToString(),
                    FleetNumber = i.ToString(),
                    RadioAlias = i.ToString(),
                });
            }
            return list;
        }

        private static readonly IList<string> JvmOpts = new List<string>{
                    "-Duser.timezone=UTC",
                    "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
        };

        private static IIgnite StartIgnite()
        {
            var igniteInstance = Ignition.TryGetIgnite();
            if (igniteInstance == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var igniteHome = IgniteHome.GetIgniteHome();
                    var workDir = Path.Combine(igniteHome, "work");
                    var cfg = new IgniteConfiguration
                    {
                        BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration
                        {
                            Serializer = new BinaryReflectiveSerializer
                            {
                                ForceTimestamp = true
                            }
                        },
                        DiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi
                        {
                            IpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryStaticIpFinder
                            {
                                Endpoints = new[] { "192.168.6.126:47500" }
                            },
                            SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                            JoinTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                            NetworkTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                            LocalAddress = "192.168.6.126",
                        },
                        ClientMode = true,
                        AutoGenerateIgniteInstanceName = true,
                        FailureHandler = new StopNodeFailureHandler(),
                        Localhost = "192.168.6.126",
                        IgniteHome = igniteHome,
                        WorkDirectory = workDir,
                        JvmInitialMemoryMb = 1024,
                        JvmMaxMemoryMb = 2048,
                        JvmOptions = JvmOpts
                    };
                    igniteInstance = Ignition.Start(cfg);
                    if (!igniteInstance.GetCluster().IsActive())
                    {
                        igniteInstance.GetCluster().SetActive(true);
                    }
                    //启用自动基线调整
                    igniteInstance.GetCluster().SetBaselineAutoAdjustEnabledFlag(true);
                    igniteInstance.GetCluster().SetBaselineAutoAdjustTimeout(30000);
                }
                catch (IgniteException ex)
                {
                    throw new IgniteException(ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return igniteInstance;
        }

        public class VehicleModel
        {
            [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
            public long Version { get; set; }

            [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
            public DateTime CacheUpdateDT { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Vehicle 唯一标识
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField(IsIndexed = true)]
            public string DumFleetNum { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// VehicleID
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string VehicleID { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Fleet Number 车牌号
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string FleetNumber { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Vehicle Photo ID
            /// </summary>
            public long RMSFileID { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Vehicle Type Id 车辆类型ID
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public long VehicleTypeID { get; set; }
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string VehicleTypeName { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Location Code
            /// </summary>
            public string LocationCode { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Station Code 消防站/救护站ID
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string StationCode { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Registration number 注册码
            /// </summary>
            public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Inventory Owner
            /// </summary>
            public string InventoryOwner { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// ValidFlag 开始结束日期是否合法
            /// </summary>
            public bool? ValidFlag { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Telephone Number 移动电话号码
            /// </summary>
            public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Pager 寻呼机号码
            /// </summary>
            public string PagerNumber { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Dimensions Unit 长/宽/高单位
            /// </summary>
            public string DimensionsUnit { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Station Code(车辆归属Station)
            /// </summary>
            public string ResourceParentCode { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Effective Start Date 生效开始日期
            /// </summary>
            public DateTime? EffectiveStartDate { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Effective End Date 生效结束日期
            /// </summary>
            public DateTime? EffectiveEndDate { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// English Description 英文描述
            /// </summary>
            public string EnglishDescription { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Chinese Description 中文描述
            /// </summary>
            public string ChineseDescription { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Width 宽度
            /// </summary>
            public decimal? Width { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Height 高度
            /// </summary>
            public decimal? Height { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Length 长度
            /// </summary>
            public decimal? Length { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Max Speed 最大速度
            /// </summary>
            public int? MaxSpeed { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Max Seat 最大座位数
            /// </summary>
            public int? MaxSeat { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Talk Group 讨论组
            /// </summary>
            public string TalkGroup { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Tag ID
            /// </summary>
            public string TagID { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Remark 备注
            /// </summary>
            public string Remark { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 移动电话号码
            /// </summary>
            public string TelephoneNumber2 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 移动电话号码
            /// </summary>
            public string TelephoneNumber3 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 是否选择Pager方式(Y;N;NULL)
            /// </summary>
            public string MOCFlagPager { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 是否选择Telephone方式(Y;N;NULL)
            /// </summary>
            public string MOCFlagTelephone { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 是否选择MDT方式(Y;N;NULL)
            /// </summary>
            public string MOCFlagMDT { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 是否选择ACOS方式(Y;N;NULL)
            /// </summary>
            public string MOCFlagACOS { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// 是否选择TalkGroup方式(Y;N;NULL)
            /// </summary>
            public string MOCFlagTalkGroup { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Radio Alias
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string RadioAlias { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// ISSI (Mobile)
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string IssiCode { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// PD 1
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string PortableDevice1 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// PD 2
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string PortableDevice2 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// PD 3
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string PortableDevice3 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// PD 4
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string PortableDevice4 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// PD 5
            /// </summary>
            [QuerySqlField]
            public string PortableDevice5 { get; set; }
            /// <summary>
            /// Current MOC 当前选择MOC
            /// </summary>
            public string MeansOfContact { get; set; }
        }

    }
}```
I run the console program code in docker. After running for more than 12 hours, docker will exit automatically. I check the system log, error message:```Apr 06 04:51:42 photon-f1d7081b1f40 kernel: Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 23767 (dotnet) score 1012 or sacrifice child
Apr 06 04:51:42 photon-f1d7081b1f40 kernel: Killed process 23767 (dotnet) total-vm:16079100kB, anon-rss:2073412kB, file-rss:45752kB, shmem-rss:0kB
````

My docker run command:`docker run -itd --cpuset-cpus="1,2,3,4" -m 2048M  --memory-reservation 2048M --name cachelibtest210 --net=host  cachelibtest210:v1.0`

Does anyone have a similar problem? When calling `cache.AsQueryable ().FirstOrDefault(x => x. Value.DumFleetNum ==I. toString ())` method, memory usage has been increasing.
The result of memory monitoring tool is shown in the figure.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

JVM heap + Apache Ignite data regions and checkpoint page buffers + JVM overhead + .NET heap + .NET overhead total should be smaller than the amount of memory that Docker may allocate according to its cgroups or physical RAM availability.

It's hard to say whether there is any problem on application or Apache Ignite side, since OOMKiller action suggests configuration problem.

Comment: Does the configuration problem refer to igniteconfiguration? Or the docker run command.

Comment: It's a mismatch between two.

Comment: Hello, can you give me an example?

Comment: Check out https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/memory-configuration/data-regions